# Turn off "Do you want to keep the last item you copied?" in MS office suite

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

This popup says it may take longer to exit if I keep the last item I copied. However, in every case, having to click on the popup makes it take longer to exit anyway, since I have to move the mouse to click on ANOTHER popup box, and realistically, I never copy enough to slow my computer down (and even if I did, an extra few seconds to exit isn't going to bother me). So, I would like to disable this 'feature' but can find no way of doing so. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/37235857-option-to-disable-do-you-want-to-keep-the-last-it It is an known issue in Office ...

Comment: See [How to not keep last item copied?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62882446/2235831) and in particular this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882896/2235831).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't turn it off. This request - [Option to disable "Do you want to keep the last item you copied?" dialog box](https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/37235857-option-to-disable-do-you-want-to-keep-the-last-it) - on Uservoice was created after the [same question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-disable-dialog-box-in-word-365-do-you/10737c0b-9017-41e1-80f0-f4b2d2333b36) as yours was asked on Microsoft's forum. However, up to the writing of this answer, Microsoft has not given an option to disable it.

The only workaround from the Microsoft's forum is to copy a single character before closing the app.

Answer (score 2):

Dim wa As Object

' before create object

If wa is Nothing then
set wa = CreateObject("word.application")

End if

' after you copy paste data

Wa.Quit False

Set wa = Nothing

'it works for me to avoid that popup occur

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This AutoHotkey v2 script solves the issue.

Newest version can be always found on GitHub: https://github.com/karolzlot/office-keep-last-item

If you notice any bug please open an issue. Pull requests are also welcome!

```
; This is AHK v2 script, it won't work on AHK v1.
#SingleInstance Force
#Warn   ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode "Input"    ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir A_ScriptDir   ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetTitleMatchMode(1) ; 1 = A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.

; All translations can be found on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=You%20placed%20a%20picture%20on%20the%20Clipboard.&langID=591&Source=true&productid=undefined

; English language
phrase1:= "You placed a picture on the Clipboard. Do you want this picture to be available to other applications after you quit"
phrase2:= "Do you want to keep the last item you copied?\n\nIf you do, it may take a bit longer to exit."
phrase_yes:= "Yes"

; ; Polish language
; phrase1:= "W Schowku znajduje się obraz. Czy ten obraz ma być dostępny dla innych aplikacji po zakończeniu pracy z programem"
; phrase2:= "Czy chcesz zachować ostatni skopiowany element?\n\nJeśli tak, zakończenie działania może potrwać trochę dłużej."
; phrase_yes:= "Tak"

Loop
{
    HWND := WinWaitActive("Microsoft ")
    window_text := WinGetText("ahk_id " HWND)

    if InStr(window_text, phrase1, "Off") or InStr(window_text, phrase2, "Off")
    {
        Controls := WinGetControls(HWND)
        for control in Controls
        {   
            MsgBox(control " " ControlGetText(control)) ; for debugging, comment out this line if it works ok
            if InStr(control, "Button") ; check if control is of type button
            {
                if InStr(ControlGetText(control), phrase_yes)
                {
                    MsgBox("Button found") ; for debugging, comment out  this line if it works ok
                    ControlClick(control)
                    Sleep(1000)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ; MsgBox "Not found" ; for debugging, comment out this line if it works ok
        Sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds good, but could you explain how do you install this?

Comment: @Grubbmeister https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Tutorial.htm#s11

Answer (score -1):

Event better yet, why have it at all? Most of us are sitting with machines with 16G to 64G RAM with hyper threaded quad core CPUs and SSD drives. Really? We're worried a nano second longer save time? It takes far longer for the user to get interrupted, figure out what this useless popup is then click OK. Just delete it. Don't waste time on more settings and options. What the point?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it saves lots of time for huge data because the app is doing lazy rendering and only generates the clipboard data when necessary. It has nothing to do with save time but exit time